# How to replace ndarray with a number?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code:

```
arr = zip(*people2)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        for k in range(len(arr[i][j])):
            if(arr[i][j][k] == 1):
                arr[i][j] = k
                break
```

There is an array of arrays of arrays. I need to replace these last arrays with numbers. 
Like this:

```
[
 [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0]],
 [[3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]],
]

->

[
 [1, 2],
 [3, 4]
]
```

Numbers here are just for example.

How can I do this? I tried to use `numpy.resize()`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just index the last dimension? If `arr` is a numpy array, something like `arr[..., 0]` should give you the desired results.

Comment: @imaluengo I use some libraries, so it won't be able to do such thing :(

Comment: What @imaluengo suggests is quite literally to change your "last arrays" in your "array of arrays of arrays" into numbers by choosing their first element. It gives exactly the result you showed in your example. What library would prevent indexing an array?

Comment: Do you have Python lists here, or NumPy arrays, or a mixture of both?  For example, what's `type(arr)`?  `type(arr[0])`?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I just created second array and wrote everything I wanted to it.

Comment: @ДенисДенисов, would you please post your solution as the answer to this question? Thanks!